# Cordova plugin javascript not getting response data from Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using Cordova to develop a hybird app for android. I am writing a simple plugin to alert a "hello" message.

So  I have a TestPlugin.java

```
public class TestPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "hello"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.essue.magicmirror" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyProject</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

       <feature name="TestPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.my.project.plugin.TestPlugin" />
    </feature>

</widget>
```

relevant part of index.html:

```
<script>
    $('.start-btn').click(function() {
        cordova.exec(new function(data){
        alert(data);

        }, null, "TestPlugin", "say", []);
    });

</script>
```

When the button $('.start-btn') is clicked, the alert pops us with "undefined", that means it is not getting the response text from the plugin.

Am i missing something? Thanks